# setState on nested map break origin object structure in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects, and I want to add/change a new property given it matches `type` and `key`.

```
[
  {
    "type": "a",
    "units": [
      {
        "key": "keyofba"
      },
      {
        "key": "mytargetkey"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "b",
    "units": [
      {
        "key": "keyofb"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "ab",
    "units": [
      {
        "key": "mytargetkey"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried this

```
this.setState({
  schema: schema.map(s => {
    if (s.type === 'a' || s.type === 'ab') { //hardcord for testing
      return s.units.map(unit => {
        if (unit.key === 'mytargetkey') {
          return {
            ...unit,
            newProp: 'newProp value'
          }
        } else {
          return { ...unit }
        }
      })
    } else {
      return { ...s }
    }
})
```

But somehow it doesn't work, I think I missed something, need spotter.

Comment: @DanielLizik you don't need to do { ...s } or { ...unit } in your map calls <-- that is to handle else condition, why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you have to return the list modified inside the new object, and if not it the target, return the element as is:

```
schema.map(s => {
    if (s.type === 'a' || s.type === 'ab') { //hardcord for testing
       return {...s, units: s.units.map(unit => {
            if (unit.key === 'mytargetkey') {
              return {
                ...unit,
                newProp: 'newProp value'
              }
            } else {
              return unit
            }
          })}
    } else {
      return s
    }
})
```

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to vote! (And accept if you find useful :D )

Comment: one question, for the else condition what's the different btw `return` s vs `return {...s}`?